# kNN Classifier Asymptotic Error Rate versus Bayes Error Rate

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour, decision-theory

Suppose we are in the realm of $M$ class classification, $M \in \mathbb{N}$.  I have seen the following result stated many times, but only proven for the case $k = 1$.  I would like to prove it for arbitrary fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$ but am struggling immensely:

***Theorem 1:*** Let $(X_i^n, Y_i^n)_{i=1}^n$ be $\mathcal{X} \times \{1,..., M\}$ valued iid training data on some underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is a separable metric space.  For fixed $k$, let $$e_n = \{\text{kNN classifier with } n \text{ training observations makes an error on test data } (X_t, Y_t)\}$$  Then under condition ***C*** below, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(e_n) \leq 2R^* $$ where $R^* = P\Big(Y \ne \text{argmax}_{j \in [M]} P(Y = j | X) \Big)$ is the Bayes error rate and $(X, Y)$ are equal in distribution to the training data.

***C***: Note $P(Y = i| X = x) = f_i(x)$ for some measurable $f_i$.  Assume that $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}$, $x$ is either a continuity point of $f_i$ or $P(X_t = x) > 0$.

---

***(Attempted) Proof:***

Let $K_n(x) \equiv \{j \in \{1,..., n\}: X_j^n \text{ is one of the } k \text{ nearest neighbors of } x \}$ and $A_J^n(x)$ be the event $\{K_n(x) = J\}$ for some $J \subseteq [n]$ with $|J| = k$. Under the condition ***C*** and the assumptions of the theorem, it can be shown that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_i(X_j^n) = f_i(x)$ for almost every $x \in \mathcal{X}$ under the law of $X$, $j \in K_n(x)$.  I omit the proof due to length here.  Without loss of generality, I will act as though this convergence happens for every $x \in \mathcal{X}$.

Let $(X_t, Y_t)$ be test data iid to the training data, $Y_n^t$ denote the majority class  of the kNNs of $X_t$ and $X_J^n= \{X_i^n \}_{i \in J}^n$.  We have \begin{aligned} P(e_n | X_t) &= E (P(e_n | X_{[n]}^n, X_t) | X_t) \\ &= 1 - E\left( \left. \sum_{y=1}^M P(Y_t = y, Y_t^n = y | X_t, X_{[n]}^n) \right| X_t \right) \\ &= 1 - E \left( \left. \sum_{J \subset [n] \\ |J| = k} \mathbf{1}(A_J^n(X_t)) \sum_{y=1}^M P(Y_t^n = y | X_J^n) P(Y_t = y | X_t) \right| X_t \right) \quad \quad \quad (***) \end{aligned} where the last equality follows from conditional independence.

Now, in the case that $k = 1$, we may take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and applying the dominated convergence theorem yields, definining $p_*(X) \equiv P(Y = \text{argmax}_{j \in [M]} P(Y = j | X) | X)$ and $r_*(X) = 1 - p_*(X)$,  \begin{aligned} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(e_n |X_t) &= 1 - \sum_{y=1}^M P^2(Y_t = y |X_t) \\ &\leq 1 - p_*^2(X_t) - \frac{(1-p_*(X_t))^2}{M-1} \\ & = 2r_*(X_t) - \frac{M r_*^2(X_t)}{M-1}\end{aligned}  Noting that $E(r_*(X_t)) = R^*$ and that $E(r_*^2(X_t)) \ge (R^*)^2$ by Holder's inequality, we finally get from applying the dominated convergence theorem again that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(e_n) = 2R^* - \frac{M E(r_*^2(X))}{M-1} \leq R^* \left(2 - \frac{MR^*}{M-1} \right)$$  This obviously yields the result for $k=1$.  Now for arbitrary $k$, I have no idea what the limit should look like after applying the DCT in line $(***)$.  The term inside the conditional expectation becomes (I am guessing) $$\sum_{y=1}^M P \left(\text{Majority category is } y \text{ among } k \text{ iid multinomials } \{Z_l\}_{l =1}^k \right) P(Y_t = y |X_t) $$ where the $Z_l$ are such that $P(Z_l = y') = P(Y_t = y' |X_t) \quad \forall y' \in [M]$.  I have no idea how to reconcile this.

I have also seen other results such as $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(e_n) \leq 1.6 R^* $$ for $k = 3$ or $k = 5$ and I'm sure it's related to this multinomial stuff but I just cannot figure it out.  Any help would be massively appreciated.